# Lidar Expects Different Rangein Slam Toolbox

Tags: slam, ros-noetic

I have made seacrh about my problem spesifically in github, and I see that this problm is solved and pull request was merged however in the construct simulation environnment when I run slam toolbox with turtlebot3 in gazebo with online async mapping I still get the ame problem as follows:

```
roslaunch slam_toolbox online_async.launch
... logging to /home/user/.ros/log/e3fd9fd0-badf-11ee-a04b-0242ac130007/roslaunch-1_xterm-5110.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://1_xterm:43585/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.15.11
 * /slam_toolbox/angle_variance_penalty: 1.0
 * /slam_toolbox/base_frame: base_link
 * /slam_toolbox/ceres_dogleg_type: TRADITIONAL_DOGLEG
 * /slam_toolbox/ceres_linear_solver: SPARSE_NORMAL_CHO...
 * /slam_toolbox/ceres_loss_function: None
 * /slam_toolbox/ceres_preconditioner: SCHUR_JACOBI
 * /slam_toolbox/ceres_trust_strategy: LEVENBERG_MARQUARDT
 * /slam_toolbox/coarse_angle_resolution: 0.0349
 * /slam_toolbox/coarse_search_angle_offset: 0.349
 * /slam_toolbox/correlation_search_space_dimension: 0.5
 * /slam_toolbox/correlation_search_space_resolution: 0.01
 * /slam_toolbox/correlation_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.1
 * /slam_toolbox/debug_logging: False
 * /slam_toolbox/distance_variance_penalty: 0.5
 * /slam_toolbox/do_loop_closing: True
 * /slam_toolbox/enable_interactive_mode: True
 * /slam_toolbox/fine_search_angle_offset: 0.00349
 * /slam_toolbox/link_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.1
 * /slam_toolbox/link_scan_maximum_distance: 1.5
 * /slam_toolbox/loop_match_maximum_variance_coarse: 3.0
 * /slam_toolbox/loop_match_minimum_chain_size: 10
 * /slam_toolbox/loop_match_minimum_response_coarse: 0.35
 * /slam_toolbox/loop_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.45
 * /slam_toolbox/loop_search_maximum_distance: 3.0
 * /slam_toolbox/loop_search_space_dimension: 8.0
 * /slam_toolbox/loop_search_space_resolution: 0.05
 * /slam_toolbox/loop_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.03
 * /slam_toolbox/map_frame: map
 * /slam_toolbox/map_update_interval: 10.0
 * /slam_toolbox/max_laser_range: 20.0
 * /slam_toolbox/minimum_angle_penalty: 0.9
 * /slam_toolbox/minimum_distance_penalty: 0.5
 * /slam_toolbox/minimum_time_interval: 0.5
 * /slam_toolbox/minimum_travel_distance: 0.5
 * /slam_toolbox/minimum_travel_heading: 0.5
 * /slam_toolbox/mode: mapping
 * /slam_toolbox/odom_frame: odom
 * /slam_toolbox/resolution: 0.05
 * /slam_toolbox/scan_buffer_maximum_scan_distance: 10
 * /slam_toolbox/scan_buffer_size: 10
 * /slam_toolbox/scan_topic: /scan_ira
 * /slam_toolbox/solver_plugin: solver_plugins::C...
 * /slam_toolbox/stack_size_to_use: 40000000
 * /slam_toolbox/tf_buffer_duration: 14400.0
 * /slam_toolbox/throttle_scans: 1
 * /slam_toolbox/transform_publish_period: 0.02
 * /slam_toolbox/transform_timeout: 0.2
 * /slam_toolbox/use_response_expansion: True
 * /slam_toolbox/use_scan_barycenter: True
 * /slam_toolbox/use_scan_matching: True

NODES
  /
    slam_toolbox (slam_toolbox/async_slam_toolbox_node)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://1_xterm:11311

process[slam_toolbox-1]: started with pid [5290]
[ INFO] [1706118226.036705976]: Node using stack size 40000000
[ INFO] [1706118228.730185739, 55.105000000]: CeresSolver: Using SCHUR_JACOBI preconditioner.
[ INFO] [1706118228.818430677, 55.178000000]: Using plugin solver_plugins::CeresSolver
Registering sensor: [Custom Described Lidar]
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
LaserRangeScan contains 201 range readings, expected 202
^C[slam_toolbox-1] killing on exit
^C^C^C^CUnregistering sensor: Custom Described Lidar
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

For a reason ( dont remember exactly ) slam toolbox was not able to recognize lidar readings thats why I started to use ira laser ools package also, and I  solved other issue bu this one in the bove persists.
My ros version is Noetic.
If extra info is needed I can provide.
Have a nice day!